# vim specify window in split like %

Tags: vim

If I want to open a split in vim, I do `:sp %` - that will, in this case, do a horizontal split with the file in my current buffer and window. `:vsp` is the same thing but vertically.

Now lets say I already have a vertical split and I am in the window to the right. What would I do if I wanted to horizontally split the file in the window to the right without specifying its path. I believe I have seen this with `+` or `,`, but I cannot seem to find it, and don't know much about this murky part of vim.

Visual representation or what I want

```
+~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~+~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~+
| ./test1           | ./test2           |
| Stuff in my other | I am currently in |
| window            | this file ...     |
| bla foo           |                   |
| bla               |                   |
| bla bar           |                   |
|                   |                   |
|                   | :sp ./te[tab]     |
+~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~+~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~+
```

The above works, but I would like to to specify the window to the left without the filename.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `:sp` is the exact equivalent of `:sp %`.

Comment: @romainl :) I know. I didn't explain that, I suppose, but it wasn't inherently necessary for the purpose of my questin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Split the current file

You can do the following to split the current file with out specifying the file name or `%`.

```
:sp
:vsp
```

If commands aren't your thing you can use window mappings:

```
<c-w>s
<c-w>v
```

#### Split new file

Split with `:split` and `:vsplit` with a filename.

```
:split foo.txt
:vsplit bar.txt
```

Just like `:edit` you can do the following:

- `<tab>` completion
- List completions via `<c-d>`
- Use globs, e.g `:sp *foo` or `:sp **/*foo`
- Use `%` tricks. e.g. `:e %<.h`, `:e %:h/bar.txt`. See `:_%`
- Alternative file via `#`. e.g `:e #`. Note: `<c-^>` is probably a better option

#### Split to an already open buffer

Use `:sbuffer` as a split variant of `:buffer`.

```
:sb foo
:sb 7
```

Use `:vert sb` for vertical splits.

Behold the power of `:b`:

- Uses `<tab>` completion
- Use `<c-d>` to list out completion
- Use partial file name. e.g. `:b foo`. Works great with `<tab>`.
- Globbing. e.g. `:b foo*bar` or `:b foo/**/bar`
- Might want to use `'hidden'` via `set hidden`
- Split variant of `:b` is `:sb`.
- Also accepts a buffer number

A common mapping:

```
nnoremap <leader>b :ls<cr>:b<space>
```

#### Window management

Moving a split can be accomplished via window mappings

- `<c-w>J` move split down
- `<c-w>K` move split up
- `<c-w>H` move split left
- `<c-w>L` move split right

#### For more help:

```
:h window
:h :sp
:h :sb
:h :b
:h 'hidden'
:h :_%
:h CTRL-W
```